# perform tasks after function is being called - Swift - NO Completion Handler

Tags: ios, swift

I want to perform some operations right after this function is being called:

```
self.view.endEditing(force: true)
```

Unfortunately, this function doesn't have a completion handler.
Is there a way I can be assured that this function has been completed (without using delay)?

Comment: Not really. I would, at the least, wrap whatever goes next in `DispatchQueue.main.async` to make sure that it gets executed on the next run loop.

Comment: this isn't safe right? @jnpdx

Comment: This function should be executed instantly though I think. Are you able to just put whatever code you have immediately after? Or do you want to do something after the keyboard dismisses?

Comment: the second option, I want to perform some operations just after the keyboard dismisses.
If I don't know whether the keyboard has dismissed I would have problems

Comment: Then you should listen to the keyboard notifications; React to keyboardDidHide